# Cakephp 4 save belongsToMany relations (save only the relations) - the cake way

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have the following Models:

**EventsTable**

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Hosts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'host_id',
        'joinTable' => 'events_hosts',
    ]);
```

**HostsTable**

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Hosts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'host_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'event_id',
        'joinTable' => 'events_hosts',
    ]);
```

In my "Event edit" I have a list of hosts with checkboxes.
Simple example:

View (edit.php)

```
----------------
Event name (text input)
Event begin date 
Event end date

Hosts-list: *(checkboxes)*
[] Host1
[x] Host2
[x] Host3
[] Host4

----------------
```

A checkbox looks like this `<input type="checkbox" name="Hosts[]" value="<?= $host_id; ?>" <?= $checked; ?> />`

**=>** I'm trying to save/update the "connected hosts". So basically I want to save only the host_ids in the *events_hosts* table.
**Problem: I'm not sure how to achieve this in cakephp 4 with a simple save()**

I looked also at this https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data

This does not work `$this->Form->control('hosts.'.$host_id.'', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'checked' => $checked ])`

& this in Controller

```
$this->Events->patchEntity($event, $this->request->getData(), ['associated' => ['Hosts' => ['validate' => false]]]);
```

It only deletes everything in *events_hosts* table for a given event_id, but does not add new entries.

---

**=>** This is what I currently use to save / update the events_hosts table. But this is ugly and not the *cakephp way*

```
if ($this->Events->save($event)) {

    $this->Events->EventsHosts->deleteAll(['event_id' => $id]);

    $selected_hosts = $this->request->getData()['Hosts'] ?? [];
    $query = $this->Events->EventsHosts->query();
    foreach ($selected_hosts as $host_id) {
        $query
            ->insert(['event_id', 'host_id'])
            ->values([
                'event_id' => $id,
                'host_id' => $host_id,
            ]);
    }
    $query->execute();
    
    $this->Flash->success(__('saved.'));
```

Comment: First of all, your Hosts table configuration should have `$this->belongsToMany('Events'`. For your inputs, try `$this->Form->control('hosts._ids', ['options' => $hosts, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'])`.

Comment: Oh man I tried this before but with `$this->Form->control('hosts._<?= $host_id ?>' `. It works now perfectly with `'hosts._ids' `. Thank you very much!
belongsToMany was just a copy paste error.

Comment: And  `['associated' => ['Hosts' => ['validate' => false]]` is also not needed. It just works.